# Using ClearScript inside Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, clearscript

I have a C# application where I spawn multiple threads. I'm on .NET framework 4.7.1. Inside these threads, work is performed and this work may execute user-defined scripted functions. I am using ClearScript as the scripting engine and for purposes of this question I am using the VBScriptEngine. Here is an sample application demonstrating my problem:

```
    static VBScriptEngine vbsengine = new VBScriptEngine();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<4000;i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(Program.ThreadedFunc);
            t.Start(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void ThreadedFunc(object i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + vbsengine.Evaluate("1+1"));
    }
```

On the *Evaluate()* function I get the following error:
**System.InvalidOperationException:** 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

I understand ClearScript has implemented thread affinity and a spawned thread cannot access the globally defined engine. So what is my alternative? Create a new instance of ClearScript for each new thread? This seems incredibly wasteful and would create a lot of overhead - my application will need to process thousands of threads. I went ahead and tried this approach anyways - and while it does work (for a while) - end up getting an error. Here's a revised version of my sample app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<4000;i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(Program.ThreadedFunc);
            t.Start(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void ThreadedFunc(object i)
    {
        using (VBScriptEngine vbsengine = new VBScriptEngine())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + vbsengine.Evaluate("1+1"));
        }
    }
```

On the *new VBScriptEngine()* call, I now start getting: **System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:** 'Not enough storage is available to process this command'.

I'm not really sure what's causing that message as the application isn't taking up a lot of RAM.

I realize this sample application is starting all the threads at once but my full application ensures only 4 threads are running and I still end up getting this message after a while. I don't know why, but I can't get rid of this message either - even after restarting the app and Visual Studio. A little clarity on what's causing this message would be useful.

So my question is - if I only need, say 4 threads, running at once - is there a way I can just create 4 instances of the VBScriptEngine and reuse it for each new thread call? Or even just 1 instance of the VBScriptEngine on the main thread and each new thread just shares it?

Answer (score 1):

With [some help](https://github.com/Microsoft/ClearScript/issues/53) from the ClearScript team, I was able to get able to get my sample app to work using only 1 dedicated engine instance per thread. The trick was creating all the necessary engines first with its own thread, then within my loop using *Dispatcher.Invoke()* to call my threaded function. Here is an updated sample app using this approach:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vbengines = new VBScriptEngine[Environment.ProcessorCount];
        var checkPoint = new ManualResetEventSlim();
        for (var index = 0; index < vbengines.Length; ++index)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(indexArg =>
            {
                using (var engine = new VBScriptEngine())
                {
                    vbengines[(int)indexArg] = engine;
                    checkPoint.Set();
                    Dispatcher.Run();
                }
            });
            thread.Start(index);
            checkPoint.Wait();
            checkPoint.Reset();
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 4000), item => {
            var engine = vbengines[item % vbengines.Length];

            engine.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                ThreadedFunc(new myobj() { vbengine = engine, index = item });
            });
        });

        Array.ForEach(vbengines, engine => engine.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown());

        Console.ReadKey();            
    }

    static void ThreadedFunc(object obj)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine(((myobj)obj).index.ToString() + ": " + ((myobj)obj).vbengine.Evaluate("1+1").ToString());
    }

    class myobj
    {
        public VBScriptEngine vbengine { get; set; }
        public int index { get; set; }
    }
```